# Refrigerator setting.... help!

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Hot point  RLA36 149 litre fridge with numbers on the temperature gage. I moved it by accident and my dad will be mad.  is 3 the standard setting? Will this be cool enough? If Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://docs.hotpoint.eu/_doc/19505132802_GB.pdf):

> The control wheel on the front of the worktop adjusts the inter
>   nal fridge compartment temperature.  The internal temperature should be 5 °C 
>   or colder although some sections, such as the salad bin, will be slightly w
>   armer.
>   The setting of the control wheel will depend on the location of
>    the fridge, the room
>   temperature and how often the door is opened.  **The normal set point (marked by a 3
>   and N on the dial) is usually suitable**.

(emphasis mine)

Of course, the best way to find out is to put a themometer inside and check if it indicates 5 °C.

Answer (score 1):

Per the manual, found [here](http://docs.hotpoint.eu/_doc/19505132802_GB.pdf), the normal set point for this model is '3'.

This doesn't necessarily mean that 3 is the optimum setting for any one particular unit. The way to tell if the unit is at the optimum operating temperature is to check it with a thermometer. Details can be found in the linked manual.

Also, the manual notes that some models have a temperature indicator found on the bottom right side of the unit. If your unit has this feature it will tell you if the temperature is okay or if it needs to be adjusted.